# set different values for NamedQuery parameters when using JpaPollingChannelAdapter for each polling

Tags: java, spring-integration

I want to poll a table for some fixed delay, and I want to select all the rows that are created after last poll. I am trying to use *spring-integration-jpa* here, but in most of the sample codes use a boolean-like column for select the rows that fit the condition.

this is spring-integration config code

```java
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class PollerConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Payload
    private JpaExecutor getExecutor(){
        JpaExecutor executor = new JpaExecutor(this.entityManager);
        executor.setEntityClass(ChangeRecord.class);
        executor.setNamedQuery("ChangeRecord.findAllAfterLastPolled");
        //todo some magic here

        return executor;
    }

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(value = "changeRecordChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "10000"))
    public MessageSource<?> jpaInbound() {
        JpaPollingChannelAdapter adapter = new JpaPollingChannelAdapter(this.getExecutor());
        return adapter;
    }
}
```

,and this is the namedquery

```java
@NamedQuery(
        name = "ChangeRecord.findAllAfterLastPolled",
        query="select r from ChangeRecord r where r.changeDt > :lastPolled")
public class ChangeRecord implements Serializable {
```

I want to know is there any way to set dynamic value for `:lastPolled` each time poller does poll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See `JpaExecutor`:

```
/**
 * Specify the {@link ParameterSource} that would be used to provide
 * additional parameters.
 * @param parameterSource Must not be null.
 */
public void setParameterSource(ParameterSource parameterSource) {
```

So, if you have some state to take that `lastPolled` value, you can just implement such a logic in the `hasValue()/getValue()`.